# Expecting None type value for PositiveSmallIntegerField

Tags: django

I have following model class

```
class GroupstageTournamentModel(ClusterableModel):
    #Score of TEAM 1
    team_1_first_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='Resultat 1. HZ')
    team_1_first_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte 1. HZ')
    team_1_second_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='Resultat 2. HZ')
    team_1_second_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte 2. HZ')
    team_1_shootout_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='Resultat Shootout')
    team_1_shootout_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Schootout Punkte')
    team_1_total_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Resultat Total')
    team_1_total_points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte Total')

    #Score of TEAM 2
    team_2_first_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='Resultat 1. HZ')
    team_2_first_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte 1. HZ')
    team_2_second_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='Resultat 2. HZ')
    team_2_second_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte 2. HZ')
    team_2_shootout_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, verbose_name='Resultat Shootout')
    team_2_shootout_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Schootout Punkte')
    team_2_total_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Resultat Total')
    team_2_total_points = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte Total')
```

And as you can see some of my `PositiveSmallIntegerField`'s are `deafult=None`. And if I save this model I get an Error
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: tournament_groupstagetournamentmodel.team_1_first_halftime_score`
Can I somehow ignore this error and save this model? I deliberately made the default value None

Comment: If you want to set the default to `None` you have you use `null=True`. None in python translates to `null` in your database.

Comment: Thank you it works!

Answer (score 0):

I just added `null=True` like @agconti suggest. Thanks

```
team_1_first_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, null=True, verbose_name='Resultat 1. HZ')
team_1_first_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte 1. HZ')
team_1_second_halftime_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, null=True, verbose_name='Resultat 2. HZ')
team_1_second_halftime_point = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='Punkte 2. HZ')
team_1_shootout_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=None, null=True, verbose_name='Resultat Shootout')
```